# Можно ли в JSP-странице узнать операционную систему клиента?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Надо показать разную информацию в зависимости от операционной системы(виндовс или мас). Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОС пользователя можно узнать несколькими способами:

1. [Достать из заголовка запроса `HTTP_USER_AGENT`](http://www.geekpedia.com/code47_Detect-operating-system-from-user-agent-string.html), который приходит от пользователя. И в зависимости от этого рендерить JSP.
2. Использовать JavaScript:

   ```
   var OSName="Unknown OS";
   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

   document.write('Your OS: ' + OSName);
   ```

Comment: Да Spring-MVC. А прямо в jsp нельзя узнать? Из-за одной строчки делать еще одну страницу не хочется.

Comment: Можно сделать через javascript, но тогда динамика, связанная с ОС, тоже должна происходит через js

Comment: Что это значит, что динамика должна происходить через js? Я попробовала так:                          <c:set var="clientOs" value="${navigator.appVersion}" /> , но получила пустую строку.

Comment: Java Script я не знаю, к сожалению. Если я сделаю такую функцию, то куда ее вставить?

Comment: У тебя с пользователем клиент-серверное взаимодействие: клиент кидает запрос на сервер, сервер в ответ отдает готовую `jsp`-страницу. И у тебя два варианта: либо достать ОС пользователя из запроса, отрендерить `jsp` и отдать пользователю, либо отдать готовую `jsp` пользователю, а у пользователя в браузере `javascript`'ом узнать ОС и вывести необходимую информацию, которая зависит от ОС.

Comment: Мне бы такую функцию, которая бы возвращала строку. И потом ее вызвать как-то при нажатии на кнопку. Можно это на Java Script? Кнопка должна разные ссылки дать, в зависимости от ОС.

Comment: Посмотри [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/pobwbj3q/). Только в настройках `Javascript` укажи `No wrap - in <head>`.